# Proper CASE conditions

Tags: sql-server

```
else if @Mode='searchdetailsallvalues'
begin
     select * 
     from   tbl_Pgm_Preview 
     where  (Brand=@brand) and (Department=@department) 
            and (CASE 
                     WHEN (@Liststyle <> ',') THEN 
                          (Style in (Select * from dbo.[CSVToTableStyle](@Liststyle))) 
                     ELSE NULL 
                 END)
            and (CASE 
                     WHEN (@Listkdia <> ',') THEN 
                          (K_DIA in ( K_DIA in ( Select * from dbo.[CSVToTableKdia](@Listkdia)))
                     ELSE NULL 
                 END)
end
```

I am getting the following error

**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Program, Line 141**

**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.**

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Program, Line 141**

**Incorrect syntax near ')'.**

How to solve this??? Even I tried using IF Conditional statements .... I need to use IF statements in SELECT, AND clause..

Comment: `CASE` isn't some form of control flow operator - it's an *expression* that computes a *value*. This looks like you just need to use boolean operators (`AND` and `OR`) to combine several conditions. It doesn't look like you need `CASE` at all here.

Comment: I tried using IF then statements but found CASE would be easier.. But I found trivial to use if instead of CASE

Comment: `and (@liststyle=',' or Style in (Select * from dbo.[CSVToTableStyle](@Liststyle))) and ...`

Comment: Let me try this code @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: And also, you might want to read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) since it looks like that's what you're writing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CASE expression:

```
CASE 
      WHEN (@Liststyle <> ',') THEN 
           (Style in (Select * from dbo.[CSVToTableStyle](@Liststyle))) 
      ELSE NULL 
END
```

evaluates the condition `@Liststyle <> ','` but it returns the condition `Style in (Select * from dbo.[CSVToTableStyle](@Liststyle))`, while instead the [CASE operator must return a result expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), like, for example, `SUM(MyNumbersColumn)` or `'MyString'` or `1+1`.

A result expression is something that will be evaluated by the SQL Engine during the execution of control flow and it must always return a value, not a condition.

As pointed out by @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you should use `AND` or `OR` conditions instead of `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause.